Encountering Error Converting Kivy Code to .APK Using Buildozer in Colab with FFpyplayer in .spec File Requirements
i am trying to build an apk app using kivy and buildozer in google colab but i get the following error:
raise DistutilsClassError( distutils.errors.DistutilsClassError: command class <class 'main.FFBuildExt'> must subclass Command
the entire error is as follow:
Traceback (most recent call last):
[DEBUG]:      File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffpyplayer-openssl/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/ffpyplayer/setup.py", line 398, in <module>
[DEBUG]:        setup(name='ffpyplayer',
[DEBUG]:      File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 104, in setup
[DEBUG]:        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
[DEBUG]:               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[DEBUG]:      File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 172, in setup
[DEBUG]:        ok = dist.parse_command_line()
[DEBUG]:             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[DEBUG]:      File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 475, in parse_command_line
[DEBUG]:        args = self._parse_command_opts(parser, args)
[DEBUG]:               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[DEBUG]:      File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 869, in _parse_command_opts
[DEBUG]:        nargs = _Distribution._parse_command_opts(self, parser, args)
[DEBUG]:                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[DEBUG]:      File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 541, in _parse_command_opts
[DEBUG]:        raise DistutilsClassError(
[DEBUG]:    distutils.errors.DistutilsClassError: command class <class '__main__.FFBuildExt'> must subclass Command
Exception in thread background thread for pid 57012:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 setup.py build_ext -v

  STDOUT:
/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffpyplayer-openssl/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/ffpyplayer/setup.py:3: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
  from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext
/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py:11: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools, but importing Setuptools also replaces the `distutils` module in `sys.modules`. This may lead to undesirable behaviors or errors. To avoid these issues, avoid using distutils directly, ensure that setuptools is installed in the traditional way (e.g. not an editable install), and/or make sure that setuptools is always imported before distutils.
  warnings.warn(
/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py:26: UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.
  warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")
Using setuptools
Not using cython on android
Environ change config_postproc -> False
Environ change use_sdl2_mixer -> True
FFMPEG_ROOT: "None"
SDL_ROOT: "None"
SDL2_MIXER_ROOT: "None"
Generating ffconfig.h
Generating ffconfig.pxi
Include directories: ['/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffmpeg/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/ffmpeg/include', '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/jni/SDL/include', '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/jni/SDL2_mixer/include', '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffpyplayer-openssl/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/ffpyplayer/ffpyplayer', '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffpyplayer-openssl/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/ffpyplayer/ffpyplayer/includes']
Library directories: ['/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffmpeg/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/ffmpeg/lib', '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/libs/arm64-v8a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffpyplayer-openssl/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/ffpyplayer/setup.py", line 398, in <module>
    setup(name='ffpyplayer',
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 104, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 172, in setup
    ok = dist.parse_command_line()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 475, in parse_command_line
    args = self._parse_command_opts(parser, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 869, in _parse_command_opts
    nargs = _Distribution._parse_command_opts(self, parser, args)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 541, in _parse_command_opts
    raise DistutilsClassError(
distutils.errors.DistutilsClassError: command class <class '__main__.FFBuildExt'> must subclass Command


  STDERR:

[INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 35):
    Include directories: ['/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffmpeg/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/ffmpeg/include', '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/jni/SDL/include', '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/jni/SDL2_mixer/include', '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffpyplayer-openssl/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/ffpyplayer/ffpyplayer', '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffpyplayer-openssl/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/ffpyplayer/ffpyplayer/includes']   
Library directories: ['/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffmpeg/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/ffmpeg/lib', '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/libs/arm64-v8a']  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffpyplayer-openssl/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/ffpyplayer/setup.py", line 398, in <module> 
    setup(name='ffpyplayer',    
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 104, in setup  
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)    
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 172, in setup   
    ok = dist.parse_command_line()  
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 475, in parse_command_line  
    args = self._parse_command_opts(parser, args)   
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 869, in _parse_command_opts    
    nargs = _Distribution._parse_command_opts(self, parser, args)   
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 541, in _parse_command_opts 
    raise DistutilsClassError(  
distutils.errors.DistutilsClassError: command class <class '__main__.FFBuildExt'> must subclass Command
[INFO]:    STDERR:
    
[INFO]:    ENV:
export HOME='/root'
export CFLAGS='-target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC -I/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include'
export CXXFLAGS='-target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC'
export CPPFLAGS='-DANDROID -I/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include -I/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/mahfouz/arm64-v8a/include/python3.1'
export LDFLAGS='  -L/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/libs_collections/mahfouz/arm64-v8a -L/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/android-build -lpython3.11 -L/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/libs_collections/mahfouz/arm64-v8a -L/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/libs_collections/mahfouz  -L/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/obj/local/arm64-v8a '
export LDLIBS='-lm'
export PATH='/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin:/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b:/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools:/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin'
export CC='/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC'
export CXX='/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC'
export AR='/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-ar'
export RANLIB='/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-ranlib'
export STRIP='/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip --strip-unneeded'
export READELF='/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-readelf'
export OBJCOPY='/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-objcopy'
export MAKE='make -j2'
export ARCH='arm64-v8a'
export NDK_API='android-21'
export LDSHARED='/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC -shared'
export BUILDLIB_PATH='/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.11'
export PYTHONNOUSERSITE='1'
export LANG='en_GB.UTF-8'
export PYTHONPATH='/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib:/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/Lib/site-packages:/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11:/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/build/scripts-3.11:/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.11'
export LIBLINK='NOTNONE'
export COPYLIBS='1'
export LIBLINK_PATH='/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffpyplayer-openssl/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/objects_ffpyplayer'
export FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR='/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffmpeg/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/ffmpeg/include'
export FFMPEG_LIB_DIR='/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffmpeg/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/ffmpeg/lib'
export SDL_INCLUDE_DIR='/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/jni/SDL/include'
export SDL_LIB_DIR='/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/libs/arm64-v8a'
export USE_SDL2_MIXER='1'
export SDL2_MIXER_INCLUDE_DIR='/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/jni/SDL2_mixer/include'
export NDKPLATFORM='NOTNONE'
export CONFIG_POSTPROC='0'

[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffpyplayer-openssl/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/ffpyplayer && /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 setup.py build_ext -v


in my buildozer.spec i have
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Mahfouz Calculator

# (str) Package name
package.name = mahfouz

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,pem,txt,ttf,pkl, m4a, json

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd==0.104.2,pillow,pycryptodome,arabic-reshaper,python-bidi,langdetect,jnius,plyer,androidstorage4kivy,websockets,ffpyplayer


i searched in internet but none of them work

I had this same issue for the past 2 days. Although altering setup.py in the ffpyplayer folder worked temporarily, I found a more reliable and simpler fix. I noticed the pattern of a v being included in the version number, which was unlike the other requirements. To resolve this issue, update ffpyplayer in your requirements inside of buildozer.spec by including a 'v' in front of the version number such as follows:
requirements = ffpyplayer==v4.5.0

I included this version of ffpyplayer in my requirements, and it worked for me. I did not use Colab, but I hope this resolves your issue as well.
Official link to versions available: https://github.com/matham/ffpyplayer/releases
